# How to determine Windows Server 2016 version from registry

Tags: c#, windows, version

I have an application that determines Windows Server version. It reads version value from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` registry key. It works well on Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2 and returns 6.2 and 6.3 version as expected. However on Windows Server 2016 it still returns 6.3 even though I expected it to be 10.0. Was the correct registry key moved to some different place? Should I rely on this  registry entry at all? Here is a screenshot from Windows Server 2016:

[image]

I have an alternative way to use Environment.OSVersion. But I don't like it much because it requires me to specify explicitly in manifest the compatible windows versions and this means more maintenance work in the future.

Comment: But `CurrentMajorVersionNumber` and `CurrentMinorVersionNumber` gives right value, aren't they?

Comment: @Miamy heh, I missed them somehow, I don't see those values on Windows Server 2012, probably they were added in 10.0. Thanks, sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, there are the `CurrentMajorVersionNumber`, `CurrentMinorVersionNumber` and `CurrentBuildNumber`, which all correspond to the values that `Environment.OSVersion` will give you.

Another way is what is described on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/desktop/SysInfo/getting-the-system-version

> To obtain the full version number for the operating system, call the GetFileVersionInfo function on one of the system DLLs, such as Kernel32.dll

That would look something like this in C#, and should work on every Windows version:

```
var myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\Kernel32.dll");
```

Then you can use the `ProductVersion` property, or a combination of `ProductMajorPart`, `ProductMinorPart` and `ProductBuildPart`.